# Hosting Windows Form Application in IIS

Tags: .net, winforms, iis

I have a windows form application that is being hosted in IIS. It was developed in .net framework 2.0. I need to upgrade framework to 4.0. When I tried, I got an error below from IEExplorer.exe. I could not see exception detail anywhere.

[image]

2.0 version is working but I could not run successfully after upgrade. How can i find exception detail?

Answer (score 0):

Windows form is desktop application which shouldn't be hosted in IIS. Do you mean that problem come from web form instead of winform?

If so, this message means the .NET Framework be corrupted or cannot be detected.You can follow the steps in this document to solve your problem:

1. Download the .NET Framework Repair Tool (NetFxRepairTool.exe). The tool runs automatically when the download completes.
2. If the .NET Framework Repair Tool recommends any additional action, such as those shown in the following figure, select Next.
3. The .NET Framework Repair Tools displays a dialog box shown in the following figure to indicate that changes are complete. Leave the dialog box open while you to try rerun your application. This should succeed if the .NET Framework Repair Tool has identified and corrected a corrupted .NET Framework installation.
4. If your application runs successfully, select the Finish button. Otherwise, select the Next button.
5. If you selected the Next button, the .NET Framework Repair Tool displays a dialog box like the following. Select the Finish button to send diagnostic information to Microsoft.
6. If you still cannot run the application, install the latest version of the .NET Framework supported by your version of Windows, as shown in the following table.
7. Attempt to launch the application.
8. In some cases, you may see a dialog box like the following, which asks you to install the .NET Framework 3.5. Select Download and install this feature to install the .NET Framework 3.5, then launch the application again.

More information about Troubleshooting this error message you can refer to this link:

[Troubleshooting a 'This application could not be started' error message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/application-not-started)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. I can access the application using url below. So I can say the application is being hosted in IIS. And the framework version is 2.0 here. I want to upgrade the version to 4.0. When I tried, I got this error above. I can not see exception detail so I don't know what to do. Can I see the error detail anywhere? I checked event viewer and IIS logs. But I could not find anything.

http://localhost/xxx/xxx.exe?OriginId=6&UserId=19057&CultureCode=en-CA&UserCode=xxx

You can see IIS path and application pool settings.

[image]

[image]

And I can share my new settings.

- Application pool is configured as 4.0/Classic.
- The application is upgraded to 4.0
- I checked web.config file but there is no related settings for upgrade.
- I executed these commands below.

  %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\CasPol.exe -m -q -cg "LocalIntranet_Zone" -zone Intranet FullTrust
  %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\CasPol.exe -m -q -cg "LocalIntranet_Zone" -zone Intranet FullTrust
- I added these registries below.

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework]
      "EnableIEHosting"=dword:00000001

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework]
  "EnableIEHosting"=dword:00000001

Note: I know this settings are not recommended but I need to run this application somehow with 4.0.

Comment: Have you tried using the NET Framework Repair Tool? you can try to view exception detail by this tool.

Comment: Yes @samwu, I tried, unfortunately it is still not fixed. I checked log files which are generated by the tool, but there is no related log.

Comment: To see exception detail, you can try to collect dump file with debug diagnostic collection and analyze the dump file with WINDBG.[Debug Diagnostics Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58210).